# Extremely slow startup of a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka application when using enable.idempotence true

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

My Scs application has two Kafka producers with this configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: myProducer1;myProducer2
    stream:
      bindings:
        myproducer1-out-0:
          destination: topic1
          producer:
            useNativeEncoding: true
        myproducer2-out-0:
          destination: topic2
          producer:
            useNativeEncoding: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${kafka.brokers:localhost}
          min-partition-count: 3
          replication-factor: 3
          producerProperties:
            enable:
              idempotence: false
            retries: 10000
            acks: all
            key:
              serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
              subject:
                name:
                  strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
            value:
              serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
              subject:
                name:
                  strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
            schema:
              registry:
                url: ${schema-registry.url:http://localhost:8081}
```

It starts in about ~10 seconds:

```
 o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'my-app-1.myproducer2-out-0' has 1 subscriber(s).
 o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8084
 e.p.i.m.MyAppApplicationKt     : Started MyAppApplicationKt in 11.288 seconds (JVM running for 11.868)
```

I need my producers to be idempotent so I set `enabled.idempotence: true`. With this change the startup time is 7x slower (sometimes even more than 10x):

```
 o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'my-app-1.myproducer2-out-0' has 1 subscriber(s).
 o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8084
 e.p.i.m.MyAppApplicationKt     : Started MyAppApplicationKt in 71.489 seconds (JVM running for 72.127)
```

How can I speed up the startup?

**UPDATE:**

I've found a problem during the startup (`Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 30000 ms.`), **sometimes it happens in one of the producers, others in both and others in none of them**. When it doesn't show up, the startup is as fast as it used to be.

In the following log, it happens only in one producer:

```
o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
o.a.k.c.s.authenticator.AbstractLogin    : Successfully logged in.
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.3.1
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1586864007183
org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: lkc-nvqmv
o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.
o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId set to 32029 with epoch 0
```

Then after having been stuck for 30 seconds in `ProducerId set to 32029 with epoch 0`, it logs the info message of `Proceeding to force close...`and initializes the second producer without any problems:

```
o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Proceeding to force close the producer since pending 
o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'my-app-1.myproducer1-out-0' has 1 subscriber(s).
o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner      : Using kafka topic for outbound: topic2
o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
...
o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
o.a.k.c.s.authenticator.AbstractLogin    : Successfully logged in.
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.3.1
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1586864038612
org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Cluster ID: lkc-nvqmv
o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.
o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] ProducerId set to 32030 with epoch 0
o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Proceeding to force close the producer since pending 
o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'my-app-1.myproducer2-out-0' has 1 subscriber(s).
o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8084
e.p.i.m.MetricsIngestorApplicationKt     : Started MetricsIngestorApplicationKt in 66.834 seconds (JVM running for 67.544)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've debugged the logic behind this, it happends during the `doBindProducer()` method. It gets the partitions for the topic, for which it creates a ProducerFactory in `KafkaMessageChannelBinder`.

```
    @Override
    protected MessageHandler createProducerMessageHandler(
            final ProducerDestination destination,
            ExtendedProducerProperties<KafkaProducerProperties> producerProperties,
            MessageChannel channel, MessageChannel errorChannel) throws Exception {
        /*
         * IMPORTANT: With a transactional binder, individual producer properties for
         * Kafka are ignored; the global binder
         * (spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.*) properties are used
         * instead, for all producers. A binder is transactional when
         * 'spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transaction-id-prefix' has text.
         */
        final ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> producerFB = this.transactionManager != null
                ? this.transactionManager.getProducerFactory()
                : getProducerFactory(null, producerProperties);
        Collection<PartitionInfo> partitions = provisioningProvider.getPartitionsForTopic(
                producerProperties.getPartitionCount(), false, () -> {
                    Producer<byte[], byte[]> producer = producerFB.createProducer();
                    List<PartitionInfo> partitionsFor = producer
                            .partitionsFor(destination.getName());
                    producer.close();
                    if (this.transactionManager == null) {
                        ((DisposableBean) producerFB).destroy();
                    }
                    return partitionsFor;
                }, destination.getName());
```

After retrieving correctly this list `List<PartitionInfo> partitionsFor`, it gets stuck in KafkaProducer.destroy() until the 30 seconds timeout expires:

[image]

Why does it block there? Could it be a bug of the binder?

Comment: instead of closing the underlying producer, did you try reset() and then destroy() on the bean? from the docs, reset() will:  Close the Producer(s) and clear the cache of transactional Producer(s). From what I understand, close() will be called from reset/ destroy(), so there may be not need for it... just a guess

Comment: I'm not closing manually the producer, it's the binder as you can see in the stacktrace

Comment: @codependent could you solve the issue? if not, did you create a bug or asked the guys on Gitter?

Comment: No, I could't solve it. I guess I could ask on Gitter...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the close is timing out, but you should be able to configure that timeout.

Please open an issue against the binder; it currently does not support reducing the close timeout from its default (30 seconds).

Comment: Done (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/891). Thanks Gary